# How do I restrict the types in a heterogenous list?

Tags: haskell, dsl, gadt

I am currently trying to create a (sort of) typesafe xml like syntax embedded into Haskell. In the end I am hoping to achieve something like this:

```
tree = group [arg1 "str", arg2 42] 
         [item [foo, bar] []
         ,item [foo, bar] []
         ]
```

where group and item are of kind `Node :: [Arg t] -> [Node c] -> Node t`. If this doesn't make any sense it is most probably because I have no idea what I am doing :)

My question now is how to make the type system prevent me from giving 'wrong' arguments to a `Node`. Eg `Node`s of type `Group` only may have arguments of type `Arg1` and `Arg2` but `Item`s may have arguments of type `Foo` and `Bar`.

I guess the bottom line question is: *how do i restrict the types in a heterogenous list?*

---

Example of the (user) syntax i am trying to achieve:

```
group .: arg1 "str" .: arg2 42
    item .: foo .: bar
    item .: foo .: bar
```

where (.:) is a function that sets the parameter in the node. This would represent a group with some parameters containing two items.

Additionally there would be some (pseudo) definition like:

```
data Node = Node PossibleArguments PossibleChildNodes

type Group = Node [Arg1, Arg2] [Item]
type Item  = Node [Foo, Bar] []
```

I am searching for a way to catch usage errors by the typechecker.

Comment: Somehow, I still don't understand your question.
My first assumption was, that you're searching for something like `type Group = Node [Either Arg1 Arg2] [Item]` and `type Item = Node [Either Foo Bar] []`.
But the empty list does not make that much sense to me. From the comments, I think that the empty list in the definition of `Item` is supposed to represent a default value, isn't it? Maybe something like `type Item = Node [Either Foo Bar] [Default]`.

Comment: The empty list is meant to represent the abscence of child nodes. And it shouldn't be `Either Arg1 Arg2` but `Arg1 and/or Arg2`. My idea is that all nodes share a common structure (namely they have a type, a list of properties with defaults and 0-n child nodes). Think XML with attached schema: every node has a common structure but with the schema only a number of properties and child nodes is valid. I'd like to do the validation in the typechecker.

Comment: My problem with defining every type as an individual data type is that it wouldn't be possible (or at least awkward) to have several items sharing the same property. Eg `data ItemA = ItemA {desc :: String}` and `data ItemB = ItemB {desc :: String}`.

Comment: You could have `data Item = ItemA {desc :: String} | ItemB {desc :: String}`.

Comment: yep, but then I can't have `data GroupA = GroupA ItemA` and `data GroupB = GroupB ItemB`. I guess I should just delete this question ... i guess that I can't communicate what I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the ensuing discussion, it sounds like what you want is to create a DSL (Domain-Specific Language) to represent XML.

One option is to *embed* your DSL in Haskell so it can appear in Haskell source code.  In general, you can do this by defining the types you need, and providing a set of functions to work with those types. *It sounds like this is what you're hoping to do.* However, as an *embedded* DSL, it will be subject to some constraints, and this is the problem you're encountering. Perhaps there is a clever trick to do what you want, maybe something involving type functions, but I can't think of anything at present. If you want to keep trying, maybe add the tags `dsl` and `gadt` to your question, catch the attention of people who know more about this stuff than I do. Alternatively, you might be able to use something like  [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) or [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate) to allow your users to omit some information, which would them be "filled in" before Haskell "sees" it.

Another option is to have an external DSL, which you parse using Haskell. You could define a DSL, but maybe it would be easier to just use XML directly with a suitable DTD. There are Haskell libraries for parsing XML, of course.

Comment: Thanks ... even though it is no solution this helps ... and until someone gives a better answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

What you have doesn't sound to me like you need a heterogeneous list. Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
data Foo = Foo Int

data Bar = Bar Int

data Arg = StringArg String | IntArg Int | DoubleArg Double

data Tree = Group Arg Arg [Item]

data Item = Item Foo Bar

example :: Tree
example = Group (StringArg "str") (IntArg 42)
            [Item (Foo 1) (Bar 2), Item (Foo 12) (Bar 36)]
```

Note that we could even create a list of `Arg`s of different "sub-types". For example, `[StringArg "hello", IntArg 3, DoubleArg 12.0]`. It would still be a homogeneous list, though.

===== EDIT =====

There are a few ways you could handle the "default argument" situation. Suppose the `Bar` argument in an item is optional. My first thought is that while it may be optional for the user to specify it, when I store the data I want to include the default argument. That way,
determining a default is separated from the code that actually does something with it. So,
if the user specifies a `Foo` of 3, but doesn't supply a `Bar`, and the default is `Bar 77`, then I create my item as:

```
Item (Foo 3) (Bar 77)
```

This has the advantage that functions that operate on this object don't need to worry about defaults; both parameters will always be present as far as they are concerned.

However, if you really want to omit the default arguments in your data structure, you could do somthing like this:

```
data Bar = Bar Int | DefaultBar

example = Group (StringArg "str") (IntArg 42)
            [Item (Foo 1) (Bar 2), Item (Foo 12) DefaultBar]
```

Or even:

```
data Item = Item Foo Bar | ItemWithDefaultBar Foo
```

===== Edit #2 =====

So perhaps you could use something like this:

```
data ComplicatedItem = ComplicatedItem 
    {
      location :: (Double, Double),
      size :: Int,
      rotation :: Double,
      . . . and so on . . .
    }

defaultComplicatedItem = ComplicatedItem { location = (0.0,0.0), size = 1, rotation = 0.0), ... }
```

To create a `ComplicatedItem`, the user only has to specify the non-default parameters:

```
myComplicatedItem = defaultComplicatedItem { size=3 }
```

If you add new paramters to the `ComplicatedItem` type, you need to update `defaultComplicatedItem`, but the definition for `myComplicatedItem` doesn't change.

You could also override the `show` function so that it omits the default parameters when printing.

Comment: Hmm ... not sure. The thing is that these Nodes have a default configuration and when an argument is not given it defaults. This could be accomplished with `Maybe`s ... but I am searching for a representation that is as small as possible.

Comment: Still not convinced. This is bound to get tedious when there is a large number of attributes that need to be handled. Another way to think of default arguments is that they don't even exist. For example there might be the attribute `position` but don't specifing it places the node at the origin.

Comment: One thing i tried was to specify types in record syntax and use reverse function application to achieve something like this: `group .: arg1 "str"` where `(.:) = flip`. But this leads to problems when multiple node types share a common attribute...

Comment: When you say you are "searching for a representation that is as small as possible", do you mean that you (1) want expressions that create a new Tree to be as succinct as possible, or (2) want the string representation of a Tree (as given by `show`) to be as succinct as possible, or (3) want the type definition itself to be as succinct as possible, or some combination of the above? I can think of easy ways of achieving both (1) and (2). If it's (3) that you're looking for, perhaps you can give an example of a type def you would like to be able to write in Haskell, but which doesn't compile.

Comment: On the one side I want a small representation on the user side. So it should contain as few 'markup' as possible. Ideally all nesting would be represented by indent (which would translate to parameter application?). On the other hand I am searching for a generic solution solution where the developer is able to add new node types without much hassle. Ie it should be able to extend by adding the new types and doing some local changes afterwards.

Comment: I saw your edit2 and extended the question with an example of the syntax i am after.